# Display only hidden regular files exluding directories using AWK

Tags: linux, awk

I have something that looks like this to display regular files but I don't know how to get it to display only hidden files ".".

```
ls -al | awk ' /^-/ {print $9}'
.ghost1.c
.ghost2
.ghost3.cpp
input4.txt
lab1.cpp
Lab2.cpp
proc
prog1.c
prog2.c
prog3.c.txt
prog.4c
script1_t03.sh
```

This is the 9th field and the teacher recommends we use the && operator to display only REGULAR HIDDEN files.

Comment: what do you mean by `regular hidden` files ?

Comment: Regular files excluding directories but that are also hidden using the backslash dot "\." command. For example those ghost files are hidden from regular ls -l.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

You can use find command for this :

```
find -maxdepth 1  -type f -name ".*"
```

Comment: The question is for the Awk command, not the Find command. Traditionally you answer the question that was asked before you answer questions that were not asked.

Comment: @jww nonsense. Hopefully when someone asks you how to dig the hole to plant a tree using a toothbrush you have the sense to say "you can use a shovel for this" (as batMan equivalently did in this case) instead of providing instructions on how to clear the area with the bristles before starting to poke at the ground with the handle.

Comment: @EdMorton - Stack overflow users are not exactly known for the reading comprehension skills or their attention to details. But feel free to dig holes with toothbrushes.

Answer (score 0):

The shell expands the pattern [`.*`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) to all hidden files, including directories and special files, but excluding everything else. Using [`ls -ld`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) would do the trick, e.g.

```
ls -ld .* | awk ' /^-/ {print $9}'
```